# Simple Normed Space Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space. Let $x,y,x',y' \in V$. Say I want to estimate 
$$\left| \|x\|-\|x'\|-(\|y\| - \|y'\|) \right|.$$

Does the following chain of inequalities hold?:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\left| \|x\|-\|x'\|-(\|y\| - \|y'\|) \right| &\leq& \left| \|x-x'\|-(\|y\| - \|y'\|) \right|\\
&\leq& \left| \|x-x'\|-(\|y-y'\|) \right| \\
&\leq& \|(x-x')-(y-y')\|) 
\end{eqnarray*}

For some reason I'm having a bit of a brain fart and can't seem to justify or disprove the 1st to 2nd inequality.

Comment: I'd recommend starting with the "reverse triangle inequality"
$$
\|u - v\| \geq \big| \|u\| - \|v\| \big|.
$$

Comment: @JonWarneke Yes of course, but for some reason I feel as though something is off

Comment: I agree, I don't think what you have works

Comment: @JonWarneke If so, I can't say precisely what is the issue

Answer (score 1):

The overall inequality doesn't work, either. Again in $\mathbb{R}^2$, take
$$
x = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-1, 1), \qquad x' = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1, 1), \qquad y = (-\sqrt{2}, 0), \qquad y' = (0, 0).
$$
Then
$$
\left| \|x\| - \|x'\| - (\|y\| - \|y'\|) \right| = \left| 0 - \sqrt{2} \right| = \sqrt{2}
$$
but
$$
\left\|(x-x') - (y-y') \right\| = \| (-\sqrt{2}, 0) - (-\sqrt{2}, 0) \| = 0,
$$
so your desired estimate is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual orthonormal basis $e_1, e_2$.

Take 
\begin{align*}
x &= e_1 \\
x' &= e_2 \\
y &= 100e_2 \\
y' &= - e_2.
\end{align*}

Comment: what if I instead impose that $\|y\| - \|y'\| > 0$?

Comment: Actually that $\|y\| - \|y'\|  =1$

Comment: I feel as though it should work in this case, since we can drop the absolute value in the reverse triangle inequality

Comment: I think your overall result might be right, but your intermediate steps are wrong

Comment: What would the issue be if I add this condition?

Comment: The symmetry between $(x, x')$ and $(y, y')$. And the absolute values are around everything, not just $| \|y\| - \|y'\| |$